# Pipeline Remove Semantics for ChannelInitializer

Tags: netty

When building a netty pipeline, the semantics of add / remove do not appear to be honoured when using a `ChannelInitializer`.

Take for example, this illustration of how things *SHOULD* work:

```
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 1

ctx.pipeline().addLast("NewHandler", mySimpleHandler);
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 2

ctx.pipeline.remove("NewHandler");
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 1
```

Simple. A named `ChannelHandler` is added to the pipeline and then subsequently removed.

---

However, if the `ChannelHandler` is an instance of `ChannelInitializer`, then this same pattern is not honoured:

```
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 1


// NOTE: myComplexChannelInitializer will add 9 new handlers when registered
ctx.pipeline().addLast("NewHandler", myComplexChanelInitializer);
ctx.pipeline.fireChannelRegistered();
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 10

ctx.pipeline.remove("NewHandler");
System.out.println(ctx.pipeline().names.size()); // Size = 10
```

I understand *WHY* this behaviour occurs; the `ChannelInitializer` remove's itself (and thus it's named entry) from the pipeline after `initChannel` is invoked.

My question is; what approach can I take to remove all the handlers that were added by the `ChannelInitializer`?

This really feels like it needs a nested-pipeline pattern, so I could just remove the nested pipeline... but Netty doesn't support netsted pipelines.

---

**N.B.** In my use-case, the `ChannelInitializer` is passed into my API, so I have no control / awareness of which handlers are contained, or if they have names.

Answer (score 1):

In your ChannelInitializer, you could implement the method handlerRemoved as explained [here](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html#handlerRemoved(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext)). This will allow your handler to remove all added handlers in the pipeline, but of course, your ChannelInitializer should know what handlers (named or class) that were added in order to be able to remove them.

Another way could be to select a first handler "before" your added new handlers, and then remove all handlers following this one, perhaps until another one known to be kept in the pipeline.

For instance, let say your pipeline is as follow (only name provided):

- firstHandler
- secondHandler
- toberemoved1
- toberemoved2
- toKeepHandler

Pseudo code:

```
List<String> names = ctx.pipeline().names();
iterates on names
  found the first one to keep (secondHandler)
  until the last one to keep (toKeepHandler or the last one)
  creating a new list of toRemovedNames (toberemoved1, toberemoved2).
iterates on toRemovedNames
  for each call ctx.pipeline().remove(name);
```